# Composer package not extracting - End-of-central-directory signature not found

Tags: laravel, composer-php, packagist

Trying to install [spatie/laravel-activitylog](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-activitylog), however only the latest version of this package is troubling, other all packages are getting installed smoothly

### Error Description

```
 End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
```

Platform used, Windows WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 distro running over Hyper.js

### Steps to install the command

```
composer require spatie/laravel-activitylog "^4.0.0"
```

I have tried this even in fresh Laravel project but the exception is seen only for this particular package

Answer (score 1):

This was solved using `composer clearcache`

After several search this led to the right solution

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/failed-to-install-with-composer